# yq read to get the array elements

Tags: bash, yq

I have an array in array file as below,

```
    networkPolicies:
      enforced: 'true'
      namespaces: ["monitoring","default"]
```

I am trying to read these namespaces in for loop.but it is not working correctly..

```
for ns in $(yq read  test/config/values.eks.yaml "eks.controlplane.networkPolicies.namespaces"); do 
  echo $ns                    
done
```

The result is coming as **["monitoring",**

But I want ns as monitoring
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with the below code,

```
 for ns in $(yq read  test/config/values.eks.yaml "eks.controlplane.networkPolicies.namespaces[*]"); do
```

Comment: Note that `for line in $(anything)` is still poor form. See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- if you have `"*"` as one of the strings in your YAML list, you don't want your shell script to list filenames in the current directory.

Comment: Consider instead `readarray -t lines <(anything)`, after which you can do `for line in "${lines[@]}"; do ...`

Answer (score 0):

In latest yq version, this is what worked for me :

```
for ns in $(yq '.eks.controlplane.networkPolicies.namespaces[]' test/config/values.eks.yaml); do
   echo $ns                    
done
```